# JFlex: Unexpected end of file macros

Tags: java, jflex

This is my first JFlex program so I don't understand why I am getting these errors. When I run my code, it give me the message "Unexpected end of file macros" and doesn't specify which line the error is on. Also, after commenting out the `%eof` code (i.e. line 18 to 24) it gives me an error "unexpected symbol" and it points to the beginning of my first regular expression. Can someone please tell me why I am getting these problems?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

%%
%class test
%line
%column


%{
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File(args[0]));
    int ids = 0;
    int nums = 0;
    int comments = 0;
    int literals = 0;
%}

%eof{
    pw.println("number of identifiers = " + ids);
    pw.println("number of numbers = " + nums);
    pw.println("number of comments = " + comments);
    pw.println("number of string literals = " + literals);
    pw.close();
eof%}

[A-Za-z_][A-Z-a-z_0-9]*     {ids++;
                             System.out.print(ids);}

(\n|\s|\t)[0-9](\n|\s|\t)   {nums++;
                             System.out.print(nums);}

\/*.*/\                     {comments++;
                             System.out.print(comments);}

\p{Punct}                   {literals++;
                             System.out.print(literals);}


                             System.out.println(literals);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `%` sign before the `eof` of the closing tag of the end of file macro.

```
%eof{
    /* Code to put at the end */
%eof}
```